# How can I limit length of a value in select tag in html?

Tags: html

Can I use maxlength attribute for `<select maxlength="128">.......</select>`? I guess NO! If it is the case how people generally handle? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you want to limit? The length of the characters? The number of options?

Comment: The length of both value and text of every option. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `size` attribute to make the `<select>` appear as a box

```
<select size="5">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
</select>
```

To limit the length of text, add

```
select option {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cSSjF/433/)

Comment: I'm looking for the limit on the value and text of every option. Thanks.

Comment: @Elyor - I don't think, its right (not sure). I checked demo link. Size is 5 but displaying value is greater than 5 and i think if size is greater than 5, it shows ............ (dot at the end), it should not be....Please clear my doubt if i am wrong. size attribute means - how many total no. of option tag value will display.

Comment: @shivaR `size 5` shows 5 options in the box. if you dont want dots, remove `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to change the length you just change value 100 from `max-width: 100px;`

Comment: Safari requires the CSS to be applied to `select`, not `select option`. Safari iOS further requires `max-width` to be applied as an inline style, to override Apple's re-styling tricks.